# A Sonos Music API (SMAPI) implementation, during the test service getting unable to play music connection to service was lost

Tags: sonos

Have setup dummy service with static value in php and till to getMediaURI method everything is working means getting that list and all but once clicking on item to play song in sonos speaker getting unable to play music due to service was lost error.

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your service? Watch the REST calls it gets, see if any return errors, rinse and repeat until it doesn't. Post the calls here if you like, but going to need more than this description to help further.

Comment: For reference snapshots have been attached https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pXnbpsvwROXxJkVMGr7fU7U_jt3AQqVx/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WGk0NMLHINT2MCpcZ9bB6mutLJYsnAm6/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uq1EIG3NJ-gLl7wU_8EHwUh8qra2YHbu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also the links which help you to get a better idea.  http://upgrade.ichillmusic.com/sonoscallback.php http://upgrade.ichillmusic.com/strings.xml
http://upgrade.ichillmusic.com/pmap.xml

Comment: Dummy request detail https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iswPFwn5amvFbiR7srFf83jh9Whxq_EQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed in your samples that the `<id>` format appears to be inconsistent. The format is sometimes `<ns:id>track61</ns:id>` and sometimes delimited with a colon `<ns1:id>track:610294458</ns1:id>`. SMAPI will often choke if the requested `<id>` doesn't match the `<id>` in the response.

I only see the `<ns:getMediaURIResponse>` and not the request (same for the other SMAPI calls), so I'm not sure if this is what you're doing. Just make sure that if the Sonos client requests `<id>track:123</id>`, the value of `<id>` in your response matches precisely.

Comment: Thank you for your support actually I have made mistake with prefix which should be uniformed. your last line made my day.